# Convert checklist into dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is the checklist radio button code I am using right now, I would like to convert it into a dropdown and allow to select only one option at a time.
Someone give me an example on how to do this ?
I tried but couldn't get a working result, this is the last feature I need to make my filter functions complete.
Example image attached

```
<h3>Sort</h3>
<div class="list-group-item checkbox">
<label for="radio1">
<input type="radio" id="radio" class="common_selector sort" name="radio" value="ASC"> ASC
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" class="common_selector sort" name="radio" value="DESC" > DESC
</label>
<label>
</div>
```

[image]

The following JQuery function is capturing data from this checklist

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
        var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
        var brand = get_filter('brand');
        var sort = get_filter('sort');
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, minimum_price:minimum_price, maximum_price:maximum_price, brand:brand, sort:sort},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });
        return filter;
    }

    $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

    $('#price_range').slider({
        range:true,
        min:1000,
        max:95000,
        values:[1000, 95000],
        step:500,
        stop:function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
            $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
            filter_data();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Already tried the following and it is not doing anything.

```
<select name="dropdown" size=1>
    <option class="common_selector sort" value="DESC">option 1</option>
    <option class="common_selector sort" value="ASC">option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just for the completeness of your question. You cannot change the HTML code of your form elements in any way?

Comment: why you cant just use `<select>` tag?

Comment: I tried <select> tag and it was not working!

Comment: By 'it was not working', do you mean, the `<select>` form element doesn't show up or display correctly? Or did you mean, that you weren't able to process the form data?

Comment: @yunzen, YES, if I select the checklist, the result updates. but the <select> tag does nothing, page not updating. <select name="dropdown" size=1>
    <option class="common_selector sort" value="DESC">option 1</option>
    <option class="common_selector sort" value="ASC">option 2</option>
</select>

Comment: @Shijil This is important information. Please add it to your OP

Comment: @yunzen, YES, I am sorry. Updated.

Comment: There is no elemen with class `filter_data` in your HTML code. Please complete your code

Comment: `click` event handlers do not work for select options. You need to use a `change` handler on the `select` element instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect the select box to the jQuery, e.g. by adding the class attribute.

```
<select name="dropdown" size=1 class="common_selector">
    <option class="common_selector sort" value="DESC">option 1</option>
    <option class="common_selector sort" value="ASC">option 2</option>
</select>
```

Change the jQuery for a select element

```
$('.common_selector').change(function() {
    filter_data();
});
```

```
-it would be odd to 'convert' radiobuttons to a select.
```